# How do I use the logical "or" with a Linux wildcard?

Tags: linux, zsh

everyone,

I am currently trying to remove files that start with a "U", end in ".txt" or a number. Thus far, I have used this command to find those files:

```
 rm *[U-.txt||0-9]*
```

However, the command shows that there are no files matching that description.

```
ls: cannot access '*[U-.txt': No such file or directory
```

0-9]: command not found.

Apparently, the terminal zsh is looking for a particular file that starts with U, and then looks at all other characters that follow "U", and stops at the .pdf ending. However, when I put the logical "or" within that range, I get an error message. The error message says that there are no files that match that description. There are 6 files that have numbers beginning with a number, but the terminal is either not understanding what I am trying to do, or is saying that there aren't any files that begin with "U", end in .pdf and have a number.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with zsh, but it seems `setopt kshglob` should help you, as it enables `U*@(.txt|[0-9])`

Comment: @choroba Exactly the answer I was writing up :)

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, that's (with the `KSH_GLOB` option set)

```
rm U*@(.txt|[0-9])
```

The pattern

- starts with `U`
- continues with arbitrary characters
- ends with either `.txt` or a digit.

You could also use `[:digit:]` in place of `[0-9]`.

Comment: Without `KSH_GLOB`, is there any reason not to use `rm U*(.txt|[0-9])` (no at-sign)?

Comment: Possibly not. I'm more familiar with `bash`, where the `extglob` option needs to be set to allow grouping of any kind. Looks like stock `zsh` globs would be sufficient in this case (as `(...)` and `@(...)` are basically equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to write a wildcard pattern to match what you want in `zsh` is  `U*([0-9]|.txt)`. This should Just Work, without needing any extra options set.

```bash
$ ls
Ubaz Ufoo3  Ufoobar.txt  Xfoo8  Xfoobar.txt
$ ls U*([0-9]|.txt)
Ufoo3 Ufoobar.txt
```